# Operating on an uploaded file

Tags: parsing, file-upload, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to parse an uploaded file as follows:

`lib/thingy_web/controllers/things_controller.ex`

```rb
  def create(conn, %{"data" => %Plug.Upload{content_type: "application/octet-stream", filename: basename, path: dirname}}) do
    things_params = dirname <> "/" <> basename
    |> File.stream!
    |> NimbleCSV.RFC4180.parse_stream
    |> Enum.map(&AllThings.create_things_params/1)
    |> Enum.map(&AllThings.create_things/1)

    conn
    |> put_status(:created)
  end
```

However, when I try a POST with a test file:

```sh
curl -F 'data=@/root/test' http://localhost:4000/api/thing
```

I get the error:

```sh
[debug] Processing with ThingyWebWeb.ThingsController.create/2
  Parameters: %{"data" => %Plug.Upload{content_type: "application/octet-stream", filename: "test", path: "/tmp/plug-1514/multipart-1514490176-65282591343221-1"}}
  Pipelines: [:api]
[info] Sent 500 in 55ms
[error] #PID<0.544.0> running ThingyWeb.Endpoint terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: POST /api/thing
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (File.Error) could not stream "/tmp/plug-1514/multipart-1514490176-65282591343221-1/test": not a directory
        (elixir) lib/file/stream.ex:79: anonymous fn/2 in Enumerable.File.Stream.reduce/3
        (elixir) lib/stream.ex:1270: anonymous fn/5 in Stream.resource/3
        (elixir) lib/stream.ex:806: Stream.do_transform/8
```

Subsequent inspection of `/tmp/plug-1514/` reveals that it is indeed an empty directory.

Is the uploaded file short-lived and can be configured to be long-lived, or am I missing something altogether here?

Comment: Can you try passing just the value of `path:` to `File.stream!/1`?

Comment: Thanks very much, that did it - re the missing file in `/tmp/plug-1514/`, and `h File.stream!/1` showing a file path with a basename, may I ask how that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`path` contains the full path to the uploaded file. `filename` is just the name of the file that the user selected in the browser (or in this case, `curl`); the uploaded file is not stored with that name. You need to only pass the `path` to `File.stream!/1`:

```
things_params =
  path
  |> File.stream!
  |> ...
```